# Show all the lookup column data

Tags: lookup-column

I have 2 lists: House and Room.

House list has lookup column call Room(Room1,Room2,Room3).

When I add a record for house list, I choose Room1 which is hyperlink to lookup column.

Is there any way, when I click Room1 it shows all the records exist in the lookup column?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to customize the behavior when a listitem is clicked in a listview, you can use `CSR`. This has often been discussed, I posted a reply [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160827/csr-will-only-be-executed-after-reloading-the-page/256685#256685).